# No text on Scilab gui

Tags: scilab

I'm using Arch Linux, I downloaded the tarball from scilab's site, and the GUI looks like this:
[image]

The problem is that there are no labels, or text, on the GUI menus. Any idea on why it happens? Thanks

Comment: Can you give the output of the following command on Scilab's command line : getenv(LANG)

Comment: --> getenv(LANG)

Undefined variable: LANG

Comment: Sorry put the string between quotes: getenv("LANG")

Comment: --> getenv("LANG")
 ans  =

  "en_US.UTF-8"

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue today on my fedora 33, and after 3 hours of searching ( although I didn't find anything useful), so I tried to change the system font, and surprisingly It worked!
I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Which system font did you set?

Comment: The default fedora 33 font was 'Cantarell Regular 11', I changed to 'Comfortaa Regular 11' and it worked, note that when I set it back to 'Cantarell Regular 11' the problem reappear again.